# how to avoid jetpack compose content going up when keyboard opens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-softkeyboard

[image: List of items should stay in their position]

As shown above, the list of items, the text input field and the add button go up when the user open the keyboard,
I want the list of items to stay in position while the text input field and the add buton go up as it does.

code:

> Activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        OlegarioLopezTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) { Navigation() }
        }
    }
}
```

The Navigation() func just call the Composable

Composable:

```
    @Composable
fun ListScreen(
    viewModel: MainScreenViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {
    LazyColumn{...}
MainTextField(viewModel)
    AddButton(viewModel)
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure that the activity's `windowSoftInputMode` is set to `adjustResize`:

```
<activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

In this way the activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

Then just use a layout as:

```
Column() {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
      //..
    }
    Row(){
        TextField()
        Button()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don´t know how, but it does exactly what I was looking for, it push up the text input and the add button, but it leave in position the list of items, I´d like to understand how it knows which composable should be pushed and which not, probably it was just luck.
thanks!

Comment: @OlegarioLópez Check the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).It explains how the main window of the activity interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. Using `adjustResize` the activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen. Then checking your code and sceen I supposed that you are using a weight modifier to the List or a constraint to have to TextField to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly my problem with an extra twist that it only became an issue after the activity returned from pause.

A brand new state had no issue, but when resuming suddenly my entire mainactivity was being pushed up with the keyboard. SUPER weird behavior.

I actually set windowSoftInputMode to "`adjustPan`" abd it works as expected now, which is how it worked as a fresh activity.