# How to prevent elements at the back from scrolling up when keyboard appears in Kotlin Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In this app, I want to keep the TextField at the Bottom while LazyColumn behind the TextField. But when I start typing, the keyboard appears which moves both TextField and the elements behind up. What I would prefer is if only the TextField moves up.

[Before keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SZE9.png)

[After keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzzFa.png) (the LazyColumn went up with the TextField)

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    var todos = arrayOf("hello","hello","hello","hello","hello","hello","hello","hello")
    var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello World") }
    MaterialTheme {
        LazyColumn{
            items(todos) {
                Text(it)
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = textFieldValue,
                singleLine = true,
                onValueChange = {
                    textFieldValue = it
                },
                modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White).fillMaxWidth().align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                trailingIcon = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            textFieldValue = ""
                        },
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Rounded.Add,
                            contentDescription = "add a task",
                        )
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162734/how-to-avoid-jetpack-compose-content-going-up-when-keyboard-opens/74162977#74162977)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest of your activity
see https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility